# Imagen en pygame, visual estudio code

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy teniendo un problema al querer agregar un fondo para la ventana de pygame en Visual estudio.
Parte del código

```py
background = pygame.image.load('background.png').convert()
```

error.

```
PS C:\Users\yoyoy\OneDrive\Escritorio\Informatica22> & c:/Python27/python2.exe c:/Users/yoyoy/OneDrive/Escritorio/Informatica22/Robotica/aaaaaa/fondo/blackground.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/yoyoy/OneDrive/Escritorio/Informatica22/Robotica/aaaaaa/fondo/blackground.py", line 8, in <module>
    background = pygame.image.load('background.png').convert()
pygame.error: Couldn't open background.png
```

Intente dejando la imagen fuera de la carpeta (fondo/'background.png')
y poniendo toda la dirección en donde se encuentra.

Comment: Podrías agregar el error completo?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta. En los comentarios no se ve bien

Comment: Seguro que la imagen se encuentra en el mismo directorio que el script?

Comment: yes, el código y la imagen están el la misma carpeta "fondo".

Comment: La documentación sugiere usar `os.path.join()` para especificar el directorio, prueba con eso. Algo como `pygame.image.load(os.path.join(dirname(__file__), 'background'))` recuerda importar `os`

Comment: no funciono :c, ahora sale que dirname no esta definida,  el problema es solo del visual estudio code, probé el código en ninja-ide y funciona. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: @christian se comió el `os.` en dirname. Sería `os.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: Gracias, el error ya fue solucionado, solo tenia que abrir la carpeta donde estaba la imagen y el código, pero yo tenia la carpeta donde estaban todos mis códigos anteriores y por eso no me detectaba la imagen , gracias de todos modos <3

Comment: yo tuve un mismo problema y lo solucione poniendo la dirección completa de la imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame requiere ser inicializado antes de ser usado, incluso requiere construir una ventana para forzar un modo de Color el cual se usa para cargar las imágenes, si no construye la ventana no existe modo de fusión ni modo de representación y no se pueden cargar imágenes.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()


window=pygame.display.set_mode((720,480))


background = pygame.image.load('background.png').convert()


run=True

while (run):
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type==pygame.WINDOWCLOSE:
            run=False

    window.blit(background,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Prueba este código y asegurate de que la imagen exista en el mismo directorio donde esta el archivo .py y no olvides que el formato de la imagen tiene que ser png.

también puedes escribir la ruta completa donde esta la imagen como por ejemplo:

```
"c:/Users/yoyoy/OneDrive/Escritorio/Informatica22/Robotica/aaaaaa/fondo/blackground.py"
```

Comment: Hola,  use un código parecido, el error ya fue solucionado. "solución: abrir solo la carpeta en donde se encuentra el código y la imagen", igual, gracias <3